# Ubuntu Splitting a file into three files with a third of the number of total lines in each

Tags: perl, shell, ubuntu

I have a simple ascii text file with a string in each line, something like

```
aa1
aa2
ab1
...
```

with a total of N lines. I know I can use the split command to split it out into a fixed number of lines per file. How do I specify the number of files I want to split it into and let split decide how many lines go into each file. For example if the file had 100 lines, I want to be able to specify

```
split 3 foo.txt
```

and it would write out three files xaa xab and xac each with 33, 33 and 34 lines. Is this even possible? Or do I write a custom Perl script for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
split -n 3 file
```

see

```
man split | less +/'^\s*-n'
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no option for that[*]

You could use 'wc' to get the number of lines, and divide by 3, so it's few lines of whatever scripting you want to use.

([*]update: on ubuntu there is, and that's what the question was about. -n Does not seem to be there on all linux, or older).

Comment: I'm on 10.10 (older version) and it does not have -n option.

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment that you do not have the -n option in your `split`, here is a slightly hackier approach you could take.

```
lines=`wc -l < foo.txt`
lines=$((lines/3+1))
split $lines foo.txt
```

If you do this often you could store it in a script by taking in the number of splits and filename as follows:

```
splits=$1
filename=$2
lines=`wc -l < $filename`
lines=$((lines/$splits+1))
split $lines $filename
```

Answer (score 0):

If your split implementation doesn't accept `-n` paramater you can use this bash function:

```
function split_n() { split -l $((($1+`wc -l <"$2"`-1)/$1)) "$2" "${3:-$2.}"; }
```

You can invoke it as

```
split_n 3 file.txt
```

or

```
split_n 3 file.txt prefix
```